# How to see everything in the NVRAM

Tags: terminal, nvram

I know you can show the contents of the NVRAM with `sudo nvram -x -p`, but doing that doesn't seem to list everything. I say this because I just had an issue with the resolution of my screen at boot, resetting the NVRAM fixed it. However, I compared the output of that command before and after clearing the NVRAM, and it is identical. Are there more variables in there that can't be seen with the traditional `sudo nvram -x -p`? If so, can they be seen with another method?

Comment: What you see is what you get.

Answer (score 3):

In a Terminal type `man nvram` and press: <kbd>enter</kbd>

You'll see that the `-p` *option* states:

> Print all of the firmware variables.

Therefore whatever it prints, is what's stored in `NVRAM`.

There should not be any hidden *variables*, however the output for some *variables* may not be in what's generally considered as *human readable format*.

Comment: according to the CIA there are hidden variables.  See this article: https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/page_26968084.html